# BizTalk Monitoring Alerts

Tags: monitoring, biztalk

I'm looking for the best way for my organization to implement some BizTalk monitoring that will notify us when messages are being suspended.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at [System Center Operations Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634498.aspx) or [BizTalk 360](http://biztalk360.com/).

Comment: If you have a custom service already monitoring suspended messages you can publish event to a cloud based notification service like [**Knowvent**](http://www.knowvent.com).  This can be used across your entire enterprise, not just on BizTalk

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at this option, it helps to notify not just suspended instances, you can look out for any states like active, ready-to-run, dehydrated etc

http://blogs.biztalk360.com/what-is-biztalk-service-instances-suspended-active-schedule-etc-and-how-to-monitor-it/

Answer (score 0):

If your project is fairly simple, it is also possible to do it entirely in Biztalk, using BAM and BAM Alerts. A good book is 'Pro Business Activity Monitoring in Biztalk 2009' which has a chapter 'Monitoring Biztalk Status using BAM'. 
Briefly, this is what you do for a simple routing based scenario, where you have a receive port, orchestration/map to transform the incoming message and a send port.

1. Define a BAM Activity for Inbound/Outbound properties like filename, received (timestamp), sent(timestamp), messageid etc.
2. Create views and then deploy your BAM Activity.
3. Configure Tracking Profile Editor to start monitoring the ports and apply your changes.
4. Create a BAM alert, where the send port timestamp (sent) is empty and the receive port timestamp (received) is in the past 1 hour.
5. Add subscribers to the newly created Alert.

This will alert any situation, where you have received a file and did not send it out even after 1 hour ( configurable), which most probably will end up as a suspended message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use power shell script to get email alert for suspended messages for BizTalk.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/BizTalk-Suspended-Service-12f5342e

Attached script will be use for monitoring suspended message.