# How to track BizTalk not processing a schedule message?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

I am working on Biztalk 2013 and new to biztalk.

I am wondering if I can track if my orchestration is started or not. Can I get an error message if my orchestration is not started.

I am reading a flat file from a shared folder scheduled for particular time. if in case the shared folder does not contain file then I want to notify an error that folder is empty and orchestration is not started.
I am looking for inbuilt mechansim

Please help.

Comment: BizTalk doesn't come with its own scheduler. What is the scheduling mechanism that generates the file? It would be more appropriate and less complex to make the process produces the file at the scheduled time log if there is no output. You could then have BizTalk handle the log if you still require that BizTalk show an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is implement a watcher Orchestration pattern that subscribes to at least one message from the file you are receiving.  For example, the first if you are debatching.

The watcher would basically be a Sequential Convoy that does no real processing.

You would set the Delay Shape to the maximum time to wait for a following file.  If the Delay fires, you can send an alert, e-mail, Event Log, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It looks ok but is there any inbuilt mechansim to acknowledge if the orchestration started or not..

Comment: Nothing built-it but you can always send do an alert on your own when it does start.  Send a Message or write to the Event Log for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BAM tracking profile and have it send out an alert of if no files were received for a certain period from that port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Can you please elaborate more onto this ? I mean how I will monitor it thru BAM ..

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question. It gives you the basic steps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303912/biztalk-monitoring-alerts  Not the accepted answer though, but the other one discussing BAM.